# Loops in jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, for-loop, jquery-selectors

So this should be a very simple loop, but it's not working for me.

```
    for(var j = 1, len = $('#account .person').length; j <= len; j++) {

    $('#a' + j).click( function(){ 
        $('#account' + j).css({left:'0%'});
    });

    };
```

I was hoping this would spit out....

```
  $('#a1').click( function(){
      $('#account1').css({left:'0%'});
  });
 $('#a2').click( function(){
      $('#account2').css({left:'0%'});
  });
/* (etc......)  */
```

Comment: See each() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: what you mean? like on click events in loop?

Comment: what error you are facing?

Comment: If you're making the same change to every element, and each of your #a_ have .person class, you can simply do `$("#account .person").css({left: '0%' } );`

Comment: @SetSailMedia that should be an answer, not a comment. I'd surely upvote it.

Comment: Why not just `$('[id^="account"]')`

Comment: your selector isn't going to select anything with '#account' if your ids are in fact '#account1'

Comment: nothing is happening on click. How would I use each when I only want the individual button clicked to slide it's corresponding element over? Is there a better method than what I'm doing?

Comment: `.each()` works to loop through all the .person elements, then sets up the .click() trigger on each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're making the same change to every element, and each of your `#a__` elements are in fact the same as `.person` class elements, you can simply do:

`$("#account .person").css({left: '0%' } );`

No need to loop through. If they are not related, and you need the loop, use `.each()` as stated in the comments:

```
var j =1;
$("#account .person").each( function(){
    j++;
    $('#a' + j).data( 'num', j );
    $('#a' + j).click( function(){ 
        $('#account' + $(this).data('num') ).css({left:'0%'});
    });
});
```

Comment: this one works also, but I had to change the var j = 0 because it was skipping the first element for some reason

Answer (score 1):

The function in

```
$('#a' + j).click( function(){ 
    $('#account' + j).css({left:'0%'});
});
```

creates a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). In short, js interpreter keeps local variables alive even after the block finishes, but it does not copy it. So, by the time click event happends, the `for` block is **already finished**, and the value of `j` left as it was for the final iteration.

In order to avoid that, determine the `j` in the function from what you have, namely, the element you are attaching the handler, like this (*warning: not tested*):

```
 $('#a' + j).click( function(){ 
    var correct_j = $(this).attr('id').replace('a','');
    $('#account' + correct_j ).css({left:'0%'});
 });
```

Comment: @SetSailMedia Typo obviously. Thanks for the catch :)

Answer (score 0):

Someone added this as an answer and then deleted it for some reason, but it works for me.

```
$('[id^="a"]').click( function(){
 $('#account'+this.id.match(/(\d+)$/)[0]).css({left:'0%'});
});
```

Is there some reason I shouldn't use this method?

Comment: Yes, using RegEx like that will make your code very unreadable. RegEx is not appropriate here. It will also perform worse than a `for` loop